# How can we apply pseudo selector to a jQuery DOM variable?

Tags: jquery

we can use `$('body>div:lt(2)')` to get the first 2 `DIV`s in the `body`, if `body>div` has been assigned to a variable:

```
var s = $('body>div')
```

can we still use the pseudo selector or other ways to get the first 2 `DIV`s in refrence to the variable? Of course, s:lt(2) won't work. What I can think of is `$(s.slice(0,2))`, but is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method, which allows, among other things, a selector argument for filtering the selected nodes in a jQuery object.

```
var filtered = s.filter(':lt(2)');
```

Note that this does not modify the original value of `s`, so you'll have all of your `div`s in `s`, and your filtered `div`s in `filtered`.

---

Alternatively, as you've already stated and has been discussed in the comments, you can use [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

```
var sliced = $(s.slice(0,2));
```

This technically performs faster than `.filter()`. However, it also may make your code less readable/understandable. The performance gain is also likely to be extremely negligible unless you perform this operation many thousands of times or more in a very short period of time.

Readability vs. performance is a battle fought often in programming, and ultimately you're the only one who can decide which one wins out for your own code.

Comment: In terms of performance, using `slice()` is better since you're relying on native JS functionality.

Comment: 1+ .. I don't see why this was downvoted. It does exactly what the OP wants. Performance is likely negligible.

Comment: It got downvoted because OP wants a better way. While this answer provides a better way in term of readability this variant is not the best in terms of performance compared with the OP's suggested alternative.

Comment: @AlexL I highly doubt that the performance difference of filtering a single collection would be much of an issue

Comment: @AlexL It is more performant, but would it be that much of a difference? I find `slice` to be much less readable. Better doesn't necessarily equal better performance. This also fulfills OP's desire to use the pseudo selector.

Comment: @AlexL You already said that in your first comment. No one is arguing that point. Everyone else is comparing how *worthwhile* that performance gain is, vs. other factors such as how readable/understandable the code is.